# How to have the program constantly check for while statement conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making this code for a simple food menu type thing and want to limit the user at 6 items. I am using  while statement with a lessthan or equal to 6, but it keeps running even if orderitems > 6. How do I get python to stop the while statement if orderitems >6?

```
foodorders = []
drinkorders = []
orderitems=0
while orderitems <= 6:
    print("SANDWHICH MENU")
    print("BLT.......... 5.99")
    print("FRENCH DIP .......... 7.99")
    print("TURKEY CLUB .......... 4.99")
    print("TRUFFLE .......... 11.99")
    print("GRILLED CHEESE.......... 3.99")
    moresand="yes"
    while moresand=="yes":
        print("Which sandwhich do you want?")
        sand=str(input())
        foodorders.append(sand)
        orderitems=orderitems+1
        print("Would you like another sandwhich?")
        moresand=str(input())
    else:
        print("SOUP MENU")
        print("FRENCH ONION .......... 5.99")
        print("BROCCOLI .......... 3.99")
        print("CLAM CHOWDER .......... 4.99")
        print("SPLIT PEA .......... 3.99")
        print("CHCIKEN NOODLE .......... 2.99")
        moresoup="yes"
        while moresoup=="yes":
            print("Which soup do you want?")
            soup=str(input())
            foodorders.append(soup)
            orderitems=orderitems+1
            print("Would you like another soup?")
            moresoup=str(input())
        else:
            print("DRINK MENU")
            print("SMALL .......... 1.99")
            print("MEDIUM .......... 2.99")
            print("LARGE .......... 3.99")
            moresoda="yes"
            while moresoda=="yes":
                print("Which soda do you want?")
                soda=str(input())
                drinkorders.append(soda)
                orderitems=orderitems+1
                print("Would you like another soda?")
                moresoda=str(input())
            else:
                print("Thank you for shopping!")
    print("Your food orders are:")
    for foodorder in foodorders:
        print("A",foodorder)
    print("Your drink orders are:")
    for drinkorder in drinkorders:
        print("A",drinkorder,"Soda")

else:
    print("Looks like that's all of our stock, sorry about that! Have a great rest of your day!")
    print("Your final food orders are:")
    for foodorder in foodorders:
        print("A",foodorder)
    print("Your drink orders are:")
    for drinkorder in drinkorders:
        print("A",drinkorder,"Soda")
```

Comment: You would need to re-factor your code if you want it to break at max 6 items otherwise add in A LOT of if statements to check for `orderitems >= 6`

Comment: Your first while statement is correct, but because you have nested while statements, this test is not run as often as you think.

Comment: You may accept the answer that gave you a solution. Another peer may find this question/answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not have a program to constantly check the while statement. It will be checked only once per loop.
You may use an if statement to recheck the condition in the while loop.
You can use break to stop a while loop:

```
foodorders = []
drinkorders = []
orderitems=0
while orderitems < 7:  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  -> 6 orders
    print("SANDWHICH MENU")
    print("BLT.......... 5.99")
    print("FRENCH DIP .......... 7.99")
    print("TURKEY CLUB .......... 4.99")
    print("TRUFFLE .......... 11.99")
    print("GRILLED CHEESE.......... 3.99")
    moresand="yes"
    while moresand=="yes":
        print("Which sandwhich do you want?")
        sand=str(input())
        foodorders.append(sand)
        orderitems=orderitems+1
        if orderitems >= 6: break
        print("Would you like another sandwhich?")
        moresand=str(input())
    else:
        print("SOUP MENU")
        print("FRENCH ONION .......... 5.99")
        print("BROCCOLI .......... 3.99")
        print("CLAM CHOWDER .......... 4.99")
        print("SPLIT PEA .......... 3.99")
        print("CHCIKEN NOODLE .......... 2.99")
        moresoup="yes"
        while moresoup=="yes":
            print("Which soup do you want?")
            soup=str(input())
            foodorders.append(soup)
            orderitems=orderitems+1
            if orderitems >= 6: break
            print("Would you like another soup?")
            moresoup=str(input())
        else:
            print("DRINK MENU")
            print("SMALL .......... 1.99")
            print("MEDIUM .......... 2.99")
            print("LARGE .......... 3.99")
            moresoda="yes"
            while moresoda=="yes":
                print("Which soda do you want?")
                soda=str(input())
                drinkorders.append(soda)
                orderitems=orderitems+1
                if orderitems >= 6: break
                print("Would you like another soda?")
                moresoda=str(input())
            else:
                print("Thank you for shopping!")
    print("Your food orders are:")
    for foodorder in foodorders:
        print("A",foodorder)
    print("Your drink orders are:")
    for drinkorder in drinkorders:
        print("A",drinkorder,"Soda")

else:
    print("Looks like that's all of our stock, sorry about that! Have a great rest of your day!")
    print("Your final food orders are:")
    for foodorder in foodorders:
        print("A",foodorder)
```

Comment: Your test should either be `x >= 6` or `x > 5`

Comment: Every break should be at > 5. The OP wants 6 items and is starting at 0.

Comment: Thanks! I missed it! @AlexanderColloredo-Mansfeld It's my pleasure!

Comment: This solution will still ask the user for 7th time

Comment: @theBrainyGeek I fixed OP's algorithm too!

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing to do will be to change
    `while moresand=="yes":` to `while moresand=="yes" and orderitems <= 5:`
Do the same for moreSoup and moreSoda.